# ADO Recordset error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a simple table with two fields that I want to open using ADO recordsets. Here is the code:

```
Dim Colcon As ADODB.Connection
        Set Colcon = CurrentProject.Connection
        Dim ColRs As New ADODB.Recordset
        ColRs.ActiveConnection = Colcon

    Dim ColSQL As String
    ColSQL = "SELECT ColTbl.LastDate, ColTbl.ColCode"
    ColSQL = ColSQL + " FROM ColTbl"
    ColRs.Open ColSQL
```

On the open I get 'Class not registered'

Access 2010, windows 7

Comment: Does your code compile? Check that first please from menu `Debug | Compile`

Comment: Have you added a reference to ADO ?

Comment: I made an error in my environment. Its Office 365, Windows 10, which I think is the problem.  I compiled the app, and I repaired office on line and the problem persists.  The area number of different issues with this error on the web, each with it's own solution.  Hope someone else had the problem and has a solution.

Comment: Office 365 includes Access? I was unaware of this

Comment: It's on my desk top for $39/Year.  Yes there is a reference to ADO.  The program runs great on window 7 with access 10.

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts -

(1) is your reference pointing to the right version of ADO (usually the latest version, which for you is probably 6.[something]?
(2) Your recordset open statement should specify a cursor type and lock type, and depending on your referenced version, the absence of these things might be able to explain it.

```
ColRs.Open "SELECT * FROM table_name", CurrentProject.Connection _
    , adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion and it gave me the same error.  I even made sure I have the 32 bit version of office, since the app executes on a 32 bit version with Windows 7.  Could it be Windows? Nothing on the web about that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question is that there is no answer.  I just got off a 1 hour call to MS support and the only way they will have an engineer look at the problem is for me to pay $499.  They have no answer to the problem, or none that you can get to.  The problem is in Office 365 since the app runs perfectly in Office 10.  I post this in case some one else encounters this problem.